# Factorial of a number in JavaScript throwing RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, runtime-error, factorial

I want calculate factorial of a entered number on clicking a button but it throwing a RangeError.

Here is my code it is working without the `addEventListener` but with addEventListener it is throwing error:

```js
var factInput = parseInt(document.getElementById("fact").value);
var factBtn = document.getElementById("btnFactorial");

factBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML = factOfANumber(factInput);
})

function factOfANumber(n) {
  var fact = 0;
  if (n === 1) {
    return n;
  } else {
    fact = n * factOfANumber(n - 1);
  }
  return fact;
}
```

```html
<div id="FactorialNumber">
  <h1>2. Factorial of a Number</h1>
  <input type="number" id="fact" placeholder="Enter a Number"></input>
  <button id="btnFactorial">Give me Factorial</button>
  <p>Output:</p>
  <p id="output2"></p>
  <hr>

</div>
```

```
home.js:13 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at factOfANumber (home.js:13)
    at factOfANumber (home.js:17)
    at factOfANumber (home.js:17)
    at factOfANumber (home.js:17)
    at factOfANumber (home.js:17)
    at factOfANumber (home.js:17)......
```

Comment: Seems like you are using a large value for `n`. In this case you should use a for loop.

Comment: You need to move `var factInput = parseInt(document.getElementById("fact").value);` inside the `addEventListener` callback, otherwise you only get it once at the load of the page. And in the beginning, it's a zero, which leads to infinite recursion (you only stop at `n === 1` so when `n === 0` it never stops).

Comment: Thank you so much ! :) it's working fine just like I wanted. I am new to JavaScript still learning thanks for helping me out

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is because when the document is loaded, the value of the `input` field is blank. When you try reading the `value` of it and do `parseInt()` it returns `NaN` which is `Not a Number`. So, your solution will be to move it inside the `addEventListener()` like this:-

```
factBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    var factInput = parseInt(document.getElementById("fact").value);
    document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML = factOfANumber(factInput);
});
```

Here's the entire js code:-

```
var factBtn = document.getElementById("btnFactorial");
factBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    var factInput = parseInt(document.getElementById("fact").value);
    document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML = factOfANumber(factInput);
})
function factOfANumber(n){
    var fact = 0;
    if(n===1){
        return n;
    }
    return n * factOfANumber(n-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Rather Than Making Code Complex Use This One As Factorial Of A Number By Onclick Event Instead**

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function show(){
    
    var i, no, fact;
    fact=1;
    no=Number(document.getElementById("num").value);
    for(i=1; i<=no; i++)  
    {
    fact= fact*i;
    }  
    document.getElementById("answer").value= fact;
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    Enter Num: <input id="num">
    <button onclick="show()">Factorial</button>
    <input id="answer">
    </body>
    </html>
```

> **output** [image: output of above code]

Comment: isn't it better to use recursion instead of for loop ?

Comment: The for loop is faster. Recursion requires repeated function calls, equivalent to one for each iteration of the loop. Each function call requires information to be placed onto the stack, and then removed again when the function returns. ... However, recursion offers a benefit not provided by the for loop.